# (Hole) align hole inside the panel form 1

Tags: delphi, pascal

Well I have a form which starts maximized, with a black image
I need to make a hole in the form, open form 1, open a new one,
hole inside the panel
aligning together with the form 2 hole

It's working on the left side of the screen at the very top, but it is not aligned inside the panel: https://prnt.sc/znemgc

on the right side of the screen, do not move the form, do not open a hole inside the panel, no, align the hole with form 2:[https://prnt.sc/znexpa](https://prnt.sc/znemgc)

```
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    procedure Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure Image1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
      Y: Integer);
    procedure Image1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    var
    x1, y1, x2, y2: Integer;
    ptnd: Boolean;
    AnchorX, AnchorY, CurX, CurY: Integer;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

const
  vH: Byte = 10;
  vV: Byte = 30;


procedure TForm2.Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  x1 := x + vH;
  y1 := y + vV;
  ptnd := True;
  AnchorX := X;
  CurX := X;
  AnchorY := Y;
  CurY := Y;
end;

procedure TForm2.Image1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  Caption := 'x1: ' + IntToStr(x1) + '; y1 ' + IntToStr(y1) + '; x2 ' + IntToStr(x2) + '; y2 ' + IntToStr(y2) + ';';
  if ptnd then
  begin
    Canvas.Pen.Mode := pmNot;
    Canvas.Pen.Width := 2;
    Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
    Canvas.Rectangle(AnchorX, AnchorY, CurX, CurY);
    CurX := X;
    CurY := Y;
    Canvas.Rectangle(AnchorX, AnchorY, CurX, CurY);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.Image1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
   region1, region2, rg2, rg1: hrgn;
  RECT : TRECT;
  ScreenTopLeft, ScreenBottomRight: TPoint;
  NewX1, NewX2, NewY1, NewY2: Integer;
begin
  x2 := x + vH;
  y2 := y + vV;
  //if Shift = [ssCtrl] then
  begin
    region1 := CreateRectRgn(0, 0, Self.Width, Self.Height);
    region2 := CreateRectRgn(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    CombineRgn(region1, region1, region2, RGN_DIFF);
    SetWindowRgn(Handle, region1, True);


    getwindowrect(form1.Panel1.Handle,rect);


    //Form1.Left := Form2.Left - Form1.Left;
    //Form1.Top  := Form2.Top  - Form1.Top;

    //Transfer into screen coordinates
    //Note: ClientToScreen and ScreenToClient work with Points and not
    //separate coordinates
    ScreenTopLeft := Self.ClientToScreen(Point(X1,Y1));
    ScreenBottomRight := Self.ClientToScreen(Point(X2,Y2));

    //Transfer from screen back to form1 coordiantes
    NewX1 := Form1.ScreenToClient(ScreenTopLeft).X;
    NewY1 := Form1.ScreenToClient(ScreenTopLeft).Y;
    NewX2 := Form1.ScreenToClient(ScreenBottomRight).X;
    NewY2 := Form1.ScreenToClient(ScreenBottomRight).Y;

    form1.Show;
    region1 := CreateRectRgn(0, 0, self.Width, self.Height);
    //region2 := CreateRectRgn(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    region2 := CreateRectRgn(NewX1, NewY1, NewX2, NewY2);
    CombineRgn(region1, region1, region2, RGN_DIFF);
    SetWindowRgn(form1.Handle, region1, True);

  end;
  if ptnd then
  begin
    ptnd := False;
    Canvas.Pen.Mode := pmNot;
    Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
    Canvas.Rectangle(AnchorX, AnchorY, CurX, CurY);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. Do you want to make holes in both forms so that their screen relative position matches and therefore it seems as if you have made single hole through both forms? If so then I don't understand why you are changing position of Form1.

Comment: But if you want to set psotion of Form1 so that the position of its hole matches the position of the hole in Form2. Then the job is simple. Since you position your holes at same relative position to Form1 or Form2 window you could then just match Form1 and Form2 Left and Top position.

Comment: Yes what I wanted to do was the hole in the form2 and the form1 to align with the hole of the form2 inside a panel exemple -> https://prnt.sc/zlp562

Comment: You want this by moving forms or by adjusting position of these holes?

Comment: Form2 is maximized I make the hole, open form1 making the hole of the same size inside the panel, form form 1, aligning with the hole in form 2

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to create two holes on different Windows so that their relative screen position matches then you will first have to change coordinates from hole on one form to screen coordinates and then back to form coordinates on target form.

For this you can make use of [ClinetToScreen](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.ClientToScreen) and [ScreentoClient](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.ScreenToClient) methods.

So your OnMouseUp event procedure would look something like this:

```
procedure TForm2.FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  region1, region2, rg2, rg1: hrgn;
  RECT : TRECT;
  ScreenTopLeft, ScreenBottomRight: TPoint;
  NewX1, NewX2, NewY1, NewY2: Integer;
begin
  x2 := x + vH;
  y2 := y + vV;
  //if Shift = [ssCtrl] then
  begin
    region1 := CreateRectRgn(0, 0, Self.Width, Self.Height);
    region2 := CreateRectRgn(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    CombineRgn(region1, region1, region2, RGN_DIFF);
    SetWindowRgn(Handle, region1, True);


    getwindowrect(form1.Panel1.Handle,rect);


    //Form1.Left := Form2.Left - Form1.Left;
    //Form1.Top  := Form2.Top  - Form1.Top;

    //Transfer into screen coordinates
    //Note: ClientToScreen and ScreenToClient work with Points and not 
    //separate coordinates
    ScreenTopLeft := Self.ClientToScreen(Point(X1,Y1));
    ScreenBottomRight := Self.ClientToScreen(Point(X2,Y2));

    //Transfer from screen back to form1 coordiantes
    NewX1 := Form1.ScreenToClient(ScreenTopLeft).X;
    NewY1 := Form1.ScreenToClient(ScreenTopLeft).Y;
    NewX2 := Form1.ScreenToClient(ScreenBottomRight).X;
    NewY2 := Form1.ScreenToClient(ScreenBottomRight).Y;

    form1.Show;
    region1 := CreateRectRgn(0, 0, form1.Width, form1.Height);
    //region2 := CreateRectRgn(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    region2 := CreateRectRgn(NewX1, NewY1, NewX2, NewY2);
    CombineRgn(region1, region1, region2, RGN_DIFF);
    SetWindowRgn(form1.Handle, region1, True);

  end;
  if ptnd then
  begin
    ptnd := False;
    Canvas.Pen.Mode := pmNot;
    Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
    Canvas.Rectangle(AnchorX, AnchorY, CurX, CurY);
  end;
end;
```

I made changes to your code and keep original changed code as comments so you may spot the difference more easily.

Comment: Can I contact you in private? so we can decide to combine skype, discord, telegram, whatssap?

Comment: Stack overflow does not allow us to exchange contacts without publishing them to entire world. So I'm afraid I won't be sharing any of my contacts with you.

Comment: If my solution did not work, tel me what is not working as expected and we can still find solution together.

Comment: Ok, 
This solution only works for the right side of the screen at the very top -> https://prnt.sc/zncasi

Comment: Direct side of the screen does not move the form and the cut is not inside the panel -> https://prnt.sc/znchzl

Comment: Please explain why do you need to move the form? Or perhaps better draw a sketch of desired effect. Where is the Form2 you can pick a hole size from. Where is Form1 and if it needs to be moved where does it needs to be moved.

Comment: Well I need to make a hole, in form 2, make the same hole in form 1, with the same height and width inside the panel, aligning it to the first hole, form 1 will have a design so I need this exemple error -> https://i.imgur.com/1fGYM9F.gif

Comment: Do you want to programatically move Form1 to such position that holes on Form1 and Form2 match or do you want the hole on Form1 to move while you move the form yourself so that your Panel works like some kind of Viewport?